# React/NextJS passing both children and other arguments to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJS with a global PageLayout wrapper for all of my pages that sets the head and creates the wrapping divs for the page.  However I am now trying to set a custom title tag for each page, which requires me to pass an argument to the PageLayout component with the page title I want to set.  However when trying to pass both the PageLayout children and the page_title argument - the page_title property does not get passed in.

Here is what I have for the PageLayout component:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from "../../../styles/layout/PageLayout.module.scss"

const PageLayout = ({children, page_title}) => {
    console.log(`-------------------------------------------------------`)
    console.log(`Page Title: ${page_title}`)
    console.log('PAGE Children (NEXT LINE):')
    console.log(children)

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>{page_title}</title>
                <meta name="description" content="JWS Fine Art" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/JWS_ICON.png" />
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"/>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:wght@300&family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>

            </Head>
            <main className={styles.main}>
                {children}
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PageLayout;
```

And here is an example of how I am passing in the page_title and children for one of my pages:

```
  return (
    <PageLayout page_title={"Orders"}>
      <div className={styles.main_container}>
        <div className={styles.main_body}>
          <h2 className={styles.module_title}>Order Management:</h2>
          {page_jsx}
        </div>
      </div>
    </PageLayout>
  )
```

And when I try to access that page, I see the following console output from the PageLayout logging:
[image]

This all being said, I'm wondering if it is just not possible to pass both children and other arguments?  I haven't been able to find any info on this issue online, and no method I have tried has worked, so am coming here.  Would greatly appreciate any input anyone might have!

Comment: Actually this is weird, it is possible to pass children with other props, atleast in react. Can you add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @PrinceAgrawal thanks for that homework, always helps to have someone tell you to go back to the basics. I created the "MRE" you asked for, and actually turned out that I was able to pass in extra props along with children just fine.  Created a repo for this so you or anyone can take a look: https://github.com/tsmith165/page_layout_example.

Comment: As for why it is not working in my production environment - I will have to look into the rest of my implementation and figure out the cause of the extra prop failing to pass in.  If anyone has any ideas on this, I would appreciate the input!  Will post here if I resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Issue ended up being due to attempting to use "title" as a var name which seems to be a global variable name that can't be used - and also due to me failing to update both the mobile and desktop JSX for the page.

The functionality does work as expected, and you can pass both children and additional props.  Thanks to @PrinceAgrawal for making me check my work properly :P

For a working example of this functionality, you can view this example repo:
https://github.com/tsmith165/page_layout_example